# antlr - selectively tokenizing a string

Tags: antlr4

I'm new to Antlr and I'm trying to write grammar to selectively tokenize a string. I really appreciate any help/pointers regarding where to look and the approach to take to implement this.

For example, the string "disabled" appears in the output of a device at various places,

```
section1 {
  property1 disabled 
}
section2 {
  disabled
}
section3 {
  property2 disabled
}
```

The grammar:

```
section2  
: 'section2' '{'
'disabled' a_disabled=NL
'}'
;
```

This ends up tokenizing the string 'disabled', resulting in "" being assigned to property1 and property2, whereas the intent would be to tokenize "disabled" in section2 and assign it to a_disabled. 

The expected json output would be:

```
{"section1": 
   {
     "property1": "disabled"
   },
 "section2":
   {
     "disabled": "true",
   },
 "section3":
   {
     "property2": "disabled"
   },
}
```

I have the code written to correctly assign section2:disabled to "true", but the property1 and property2 values get assigned "" because of this.

```
{"section1": 
   {
     "property1": ""
   },
 "section2":
   {
     "disabled": "true",
   },
 "section3":
   {
     "property2": ""
   },
}
```

Antlr debug output shows that all occurrences of "disabled" are being tokenized.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Having gone through documentation, it appears that mode or semantic predicates would work. We are also using Antlr 4.7 and Go.

Comment: Show your grammar.

Comment: Updated with the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve from the description, and also it's not clear how you want to 'selectively tokenizing a string', but how about this grammar:

```
section: ID '{' ID? 'disabled' '}'

WS : [ \n\u000D] -> skip ; 
ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
```

And then doing the rest as operations on the parse trees? If you provide more information, I will update the answer.